# Low cost device able to run Python 3 and Scratch for educational purposes

Tags: development, cheap, low-cost

What is the less expensive device for a student to study Scratch, Python 3 and maybe some Duolingo-style webapp?

Cost is the main issue, since many students need one.

Older PC, Raspberry Pi, tablet with keyboard, maybe smartphone with OTG and mouse+keyboard combo?

Scratch can be run from the browser, but Python 3 needs an installed interpreter and pip would be very helpful. Running an open source system would be nice too, since it would make easier to hack the device when its utility is surpassed.